# date format returned the date object in owl-date-time-inline

Tags: angular, datetimepicker

im using this library in my application for selection date and time

[date-time-picker](https://github.com/DanielYKPan/date-time-picker)

particulary im using owl-date-time-inline and want to set format for the date
i have read the docs here [date-time-picker/#locale-formats](https://danielykpan.github.io/date-time-picker/#locale-formats)

and set locale to 'en'
and set formats like docs but nothing changed in the returned date

here is my html and ts code

```
<owl-date-time-inline name="date_to_publish"
                      hour12Timer="true"
                      [(ngModel)]="news.date_to_publish">
</owl-date-time-inline>

this.news = {
  id: '',
  url_title: '',
  title: '',
  source: '',
  content: '',
  summary: '',
  extract: '',
  video: '',
  is_news_ticker: false,
  is_main_news: false,
  is_special_news: true,
  is_hidden_news: false,
  is_particular_news: false,
  is_shown_in_template: true,
  share_facebook: false,
  share_facebook_offical: false,
  is_instant: false,
  is_amp: false,
  twitter: false,
  use_watermark: false,
  seo_name: '',
  seo_title: '',
  seo_description: '',
  social_title: '',
  social_description: '',
  social_image: '',
  author_id: '',
  author: '',
  type_id: '',
  newsfile_id: '',
  image: '',
  image_description: '',
  date_to_publish: new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { year: 'numeric', 
  month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric', hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric' }),
  time: new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { hour: 'numeric', hour12: 
  false, minute: 'numeric' }),
  category_id: '',
  tags: [],
  image_edited: false,
  simage_edited: false,
  twitter_edited: 1,
  photos: []
};
```

}

in my model i set date_to_publish to get the current date by default and its works fine but if i change the date to the next day or change the hours date object will be returned like this

sorry for my english

Comment: it is not clear (for me)what are you getting  and what are you expecting to get, may be screen shot or stackblitz?

Comment: @happyZZR1400 i expect to get date with this format {year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric', hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric'} but i get the Date object as returned value not as string